# MongoDB C#.NET Connection String Format

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I am trying to connect to a MongoDB with my .NET Core 2 controller and I am getting the following error:

`MongoDB.Driver.MongoConfigurationException: The connection string 'mongodb://@myapp-a1yri.mongodb.net' is not valid.`

I am trying to initialize a MongoClient using the connection string, but I am not sure how to format the connection string and the MongoDB documentation doesn't have anything examples for .NET in it.

This is my current connection string attempt: `var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://@myapp-a1yri.mongodb.net");`

I am sure it is just simple syntax.

I appreciate the help

Comment: Why is there an @ sign in connection string? Also you may try adding the port in the connection string.

Comment: See also: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: @Corak the only parameter it says is required is the host, that's all I need, correct? Where do I find what the exact entry for the host is?

Comment: @imlokesh I am not sure, I saw that link somewhere in my CP so I copy and pasted it

Comment: @blubberbo - shouldn't *you* know where *you* host the DB. Also, the `@` seems to be the end of the `username:password@` parameters which you are missing (if needed). Just copy/paste something from somewhere rarely works exactly as one intends.

Comment: @Corak of course. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't something blatant I was missing - I will troubleshoot

Comment: [This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/getting-started-mongodbwithcsharp/) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your @ sign is causing the problem. Please remove the @ sign from connection string and then try.

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://myapp-a1yri.mongodb.net")
```

As I am using without @ sign and it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the information! It got further now, although now I am getting: `An exceptionoccurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException: Device not configured`